# how to correctly apply css :has() pseudo class to <aside> parent style?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

`:has()` does not style specific parent element in Firefox.

Working without `:has()`:

```css
aside {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<aside class="header-widget-area widget-area site-header-focus-item header-widget-area-inner" data-section="sidebar-widgets-header-widget-3">
  <section id="block-61" class="widget widget_block">
    <div class="selectdiv" id="test">
      <label for="test"></label>
      <select name="test">
        <option value="XX">12345</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

With `:has()` pseudo-class the style fails to apply for me:

```css
aside:has(section) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<aside class="header-widget-area widget-area site-header-focus-item header-widget-area-inner" data-section="sidebar-widgets-header-widget-3">
  <section id="block-61" class="widget widget_block">
    <div class="selectdiv" id="test">
      <label for="test"></label>
      <select name="test">
        <option value="XX">12345</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Comment: It should work. However it might not be supported in all browsers. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: indeed!  i'm using FF 111.  setting `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` -> true does the trick; it works as expected.   I didn't see this one coming :-/  Not widely supported at all.   Is there another "style the parent" approach other than :has() that *IS* supported ?

Comment: :has() is supported in all browsers... _except_ Firefox. They're working on it but it's not slated to land for several more versions. That being said, it _can_ be enabled manually by users. I recommend using the property and just including a note that some styling won't work in current Firefox versions; websites do this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Maybe.  In my html, I generate the `<div class="selectdiv" ...` and inward, so have full control over that.  It's a dropdown menu.  The `aside` and `section` are wrapped around it by my Wordpress theme.  They're classed/id'd with random names, which is why I trying to get to those selectors from my code ... which has a static name.   I need to get at that `aside`.  I'll stare some more at the link your pointed me to.